# Embedded rails / ruby not showing up on heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails web app isn't showing my embedded rails & ruby properly in its views when pushed to Heroku.  It works fine on the localhost.  For example in my nav bar:

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li><%= link_to current_user.first_name, user_url(current_user) %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", session_url, method: :delete %></li>
</ul>
```

The first link_to tag in dev displays the signed in user's first name.  When pushed to Heroku it displays the link's url not the user's first name.  The link works exactly the same way in both and I don't receive any errors.  Additionally, on the user's profile page it doesn't display data stored in the database but in development it does properly.

I've googled around but haven't found anyone documenting a similar problem.  I created a completely different heroku app and the same problem persists.

Any advice or guidance to how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Silly question... Did you run your migrations and restart the server?

Comment: Yep, I did both of those a couple times, then reset the DB, and then created a different heroku app all together

Comment: Have you tried to see what heroku's console outputs? 'heroku run console' and then 'User.first.first_name'

Comment: Are you running Devise?

Comment: Nope, not running Devise.

Comment: Good call on checking the DB with console - the data is strangely being saved, so it passes the validations but as soon as we call the same element in irb, all the values are nil - not sure why this is happening. Any ideas based on the new info?  We're looking back through all the code logic now but maybe it's a DB issue since we are switching between SQLite3 and PG (and all the saving and logic works fine in dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was old attr_accessors in a duplicate model that prevented the data from being saved properly but allowing the object itself to be saved.  Removing this old code enabled the production version to work properly.